# Wolfram alpha doesn't allow me to plot and display a shaded area under Gaussian

Tags: wolframalpha

I quite simply for illustration and teaching purposes want to plot the area under a gaussian between two points and have this shaded. But Wolfram alpha seems to have other ideas. For example:

```
 integrate gaussian mu=0, sigma=0.1 from 0.3 to 0.6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html Does this help anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

[image]

To achieve this in WolframAlpha, first of all rewrite `gaussian mu=0, sigma=0.1` as `N(0,0.1)`.

Then just specify the limit of PDF: `from 0.3 to 0.6`. You don't need to specify `integrate`, WolframAlpha will understand you want `P(0.3 < N(0,0.1) < 0.6)`

The command will look like: `N(0,0.1) from 0.3 to 0.6`